# Connecting to locally running TCP service from web application

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications

I want to write a little web application, where all it does is given some search term, calls a service running on the same machine which can be accessed with a TCP connection.

So what I'm wondering is, for every request that comes in to my web application, should I be setting up a new TCP connection to this service, or is there some neater way to do this like having a thread pool which recycles connections to the service?

What options do I have?

Comment: I would go for the simpler way of a new connection each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to answer that without more informations. Short story : *it depends*

If the service needs expensive initialization for each new connection (example : a JDBC connection), you should keep a connection pool. If it is something as simple as a not connected web service, just open a connection for each call.

Edit per comment :

The way you describe your service, I think you can reasonably use a TCP connection  for each call.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'not connected web service'? I am just connecting to a little word lookup service running on the same machine on a different port, you just connect to it via a TCP connection.

Comment: What I call not connected is a protocol like HTTP. where each request use a new TCP connection and has no persistent session.